# Error when creating package in BIDS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, bids

I am trying to create a new package in BIDS but i get the attached error. However you will notice that SSIS is already running.

What else could be causing this error and what is the solution?

Thanks Paul

[image]

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and reinstalling yet?  The error message doesn't really say it isn't installed it could be read that it doesn't like the way it was installed.

Comment: ty for comment. yup, done all that :(

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to your problem, but posting in case someone else gets this error: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/963070

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an instance of SQL Express running that could be causing some confusion, from: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/99386641-daf9-4370-bf1e-a52affd8c1ef

> Resolution was to unstall R2 Express,
>   Integration Services, and BIDS then
>   restall Integration Services and BIDS
>   from the R2 Developer media.